# image uploading locally, but not after hosted

Tags: php, image

image uploading is successful in locally. But after hosting, it's not working.

```
    $imgname=$_FILES["imgfile"]["name"];
        if($imgname!=''){
            if ((($_FILES["imgfile"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
            || ($_FILES["imgfile"]["type"] == "image/jpg"))
            && ($_FILES["imgfile"]["size"] < 200000))
            {
                list($img)=explode("@",$mail); $img=$img.".jpg";
                $extension=end(explode(".", $_FILES["imgfile"]["name"]));
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imgfile"]["tmp_name"],"dpstaff/".$img);
            } else { ?> <script type="text/javascript"> alert(" Type mismatch or Exceed Size "); window.location = "reg2.php";  </script> <?php }
        } else { ?> <script type="text/javascript"> alert(" No Image Selected "); window.location = "reg2.php"; </script> <?php  }

    header("location:staf2.php");
    }
    else
    {   ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Exist same value (mobile no.)");
    </script>
    <?php
    }
```

and html code is :

```
<form method="post" action="staf1.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<tr>
    <td> Photo </td>
    <td> <input type="file" name="imgfile" id="imgfile" <?php if(!(isset($_GET["edit"]))) echo "required"; ?> /> 
    <mandatory>( < 200KB , jpg format) </mandatory></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

and there is one more problem, the message is not displaying.

Comment: Did you make your directory writable?

Comment: and writable by the web server, normally running as user `www-data`

Comment: A bit off topic, but I'd probably test the file to make sure it is actually an image (by using GD with a try/except fallover, or something similar). AFAIK, when uploading files to PHP I don't believe it uses magicbytes to determine the file type. It just goes off of the file type sent by the browser, which is determined by the file extension..usually..

Comment: how can I make it writable?

Comment: there is no way ?? :(

Comment: Using [CHMOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod).

Comment: I think the problem is, the `file` is not passing. I tried to print the name,size,type, etc. But nothing printed.

Comment: ERROR- 6: Missing a temporary folder :(